# go through an sxml file in schme

Tags: scheme

im trying to load a sxml file... i manage to do that in scheme. now i want to go through it using recursion and located items that i want. my code is like this,

```
(define file (read(open-input-file "test1.sxml")))

(define myfunc
  (lambda (S)
    (if (eq? "foo" (car S))
        (display "found\n")
         (display "not found\n")
    )
    (if (null? (cdr S))
        (display "\n")
         (myfunc(cdr S)))))
```

but it seems that it goes through only the first line of the sxml file. how can i make it go through all the file until the end?

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to search through all of the sublists of the structure.  Your code right now only looks at the top-most elements.
2) You usually don't want to have multiple statements in a row (like your two `if` statements)
3) You probably want to look for symbols, not strings, in your SXML file.  Regardless, you must use `equal?` to compare strings.

Thus, your function becomes

```
(define myfunc
  (lambda (S)
    (cond
      ((null? S) #f)
      ((pair? (car S)) (or (myfunc (car S)) (myfunc (cdr S)))) ; search on sublists
      ((equal? "foo" (car S)) #t) ; if found, return true
      (else (myfunc (cdr S))))))
```

Comment: i tried your code on my sxml file  but it returns me a false value